# Residual Block works with LazyConv1d, but gives error with normal Conv1d

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have the following implementation of residual block and Resnet, inspired by [d2l](http://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/resnet.html)

```
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F

class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, use_1x1conv=False, strides=1, kernel_size=3, padding=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding,
                               stride=strides)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding)
        if use_1x1conv:
            self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=strides)
        else:
            self.conv3 = None
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels)

    def forward(self, X):
        Y = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(X)))
        Y = self.bn2(self.conv2(Y))
        print("Before: ", X.size(), Y.size())
        if self.conv3:
            X = self.conv3(X)
        Y += X
        print("After: ", X.size(), Y.size())
        return F.relu(Y)
```

and the following implementation of Resnet:

```
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn

from skeleton.layers.residual_block import ResidualBlock


class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, triples):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        modules = []
        modules.append(self.starting_block(128))
        for _, triple in enumerate(triples):
            in_channels, num_residuals, out_channels = triple[0], triple[1], triple[2]
            block = self.block(in_channels,num_residuals,out_channels)
            modules.append(block)
            modules.append(nn.Sequential(nn.ReLU(), nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(3)))

        modules.append(nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LazyLinear(256), nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.LazyLinear(128)
        ))
        
        self.net = nn.Sequential(*modules)


    def starting_block(self, input_channels):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(input_channels, 128, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1))

    def block(self, in_channels, num_residuals, out_channels):
        blk = []
        for _ in range(num_residuals):
            blk.append(ResidualBlock(in_channels, out_channels, use_1x1conv=True))
        return nn.Sequential(*blk)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)
```

And initialize the model like this

```
self.resnet = ResNet(((num_embedding, 2,num_embedding*2),(num_embedding*2, 2, num_embedding*4)))
```

Where num_embedding is 128

However, when training, the model gives the error inside the forward function of the Residual block, in the line `Y = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(X)))`.

The error is `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [256, 128, 3], expected input[128, 256, 60] to have 128 channels, but got 256 channels instead`.

However, I tried to initialize the layers with `LazyConv1d` (only use `out_channels` as parameter) and it doesn't give that dimensions error and the training went fine. I'm not sure what the issue is and can this be fixed without using `LazyConv1d`.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the dimension of input tensors.
The error clearly says, the model is not receiving expected tensor shape. If you are training your model with different width and height make sure in the input tensor they are in the right order.
It seems your tensors are in shape `128, 256, C` instead of `256, 128, C`.